# Could not resolve peer dependency between my Angular app and my custom Angular library

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependencies

I have created this Angular library that I now want to use in my other Angular apps, but I seem to have trouble with my peer dependencies. I have tried fiddling around in my App's package.json, but couldn't seem to remove any of my errors.

What I have tried (in that order) :

- Removing node_modules
- ng update
- npm update
- npm audit --fix
- npm i
- Recreating a new test app all together

Here are the errors :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: lib-test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@13.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"^13.0.0" from @my-group/angular-lib@1.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@my-group/angular-lib
npm ERR!       @my-group/angular-lib@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.1.0" from @my-group/angular-lib@1.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@my-group/angular-lib
npm ERR!   @my-group/angular-lib@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

package.json (App)

```
{
  "name": "lib-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@cloud-republic/angular-lib": "^1.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

package.json (Library)

```
{
  "name": "@my-group/angular-lib",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@my-group:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/packages/npm/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-lib": "ng build lib-angular",
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@semantic-release/gitlab": "^7.0.4",
    "semantic-release": "^19.0.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not the issue with peer dependencies. This is more to do with version conflict. I guess you are using npm >=7 that's why you are getting this error:-

As mentioned in the error log try the below command to fix the issue:-

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

The above solution will solve your problem. However, the main issue is with your library.
In your library package you are saying use the below package:-

```
 "@angular/common": "^13.1.0"
```

However, in your application, you have installed the below version.
"@angular/common": "~13.0.0".
So your library package is greater than the one installed in the application.
Either install the same version in your application or downgrade the version in your library.

In this way, `npm install` command will work without any issue.

Comment: Thanks. Everytime I get this message I run the install command with the legacy peer deps flag `npm i  [package_name] --legacy-peer-deps`