# Error TS 2694 when trying command ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I have these nasty errors when I try to run my angular application, to be honest I don't know what is wrong maybe somebody can help me. I didn't do anything special, I just added one component and after that the program didn't work. I tried to remove the node_modules folder but it didn't help me, also tried the npm install but did no good.

```
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts:29:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
29     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationInitStatus, [{ optional: true; }]>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts:30:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
30     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<ApplicationInitStatus>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_module.d.ts:32:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
32     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationModule, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_module.d.ts:33:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
33     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<ApplicationModule, never, never, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_module.d.ts:34:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
34     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<ApplicationModule>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:145:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
145     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<PlatformRef, never>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:146:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
146     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<PlatformRef>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:312:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
312     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationRef, never>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:313:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
313     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<ApplicationRef>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/console.d.ts:12:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
12     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Console, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/console.d.ts:13:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
13     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<Console>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:71:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
71     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Compiler, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:72:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
72     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<Compiler>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts:39:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
39     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SystemJsNgModuleLoader, [null, { optional: true; }]>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts:40:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
40     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<SystemJsNgModuleLoader>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts:90:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
90     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Testability, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts:91:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
91     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<Testability>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts:134:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
134     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<TestabilityRegistry, never>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: ../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts:135:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/Matei/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.
135     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<TestabilityRegistry>;
```

Here are my versions when I run ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.6
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.2.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 13.2.6
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.6
@schematics/angular             13.2.6
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.5.5
```

And here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap-navbar": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
}
```

If you need more information or code files please let me know. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with *angular-in-memory-web-api@0.13.0* and a few options i tried are in this post: [npm WARN ... requires a peer of ... but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053414/8992452)

This one has a similar approach [Could not resolve peer dependency between my Angular app and my custom Angular library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71066810/8992452)